# How to configure multiple tenants for .net core 5.0 openidconnect authentication?

Tags: .net-core, openid-connect

I am using asp.net core 5.0 and openidconnect to authenticate users. My application will be used by several organizations.
My database stores the openid Connect options (client id, client secret, authority, etc) for each organization. I authenticated users by getting all the stored openid connect options (for all organizations) in my database and add each as below in the startup.cs

```
foreach(OrganizationSetting setting in settings)
{
authBuilder.AddOpenIdConnect(settings.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.Authority = setting.Authority
                options.ClientId = setting.ClientId;
                options.CallbackPath =setting.CallbackPath;
                options.ClientSecret =setting.ClientSecret;
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    SaveSigninToken = true
                };
            })
}
```

As you see, I must have different values for the autheticationscheme property and for the options.CallbackPath, else the application will throw an exception.
Since I am new to this, is there a better way to achieve my goal? maybe setting the clientid/tenantid at runtime before calling the challenge method ?

Thank you